# Ellipses cut off text by word instead of characters

Tags: android

In android i want to have a textview with ellipsis at the end, but for it to cut off the end by word chunks instead of by character. i cant seem to find a way to do that. This is what i have now.

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:lines="1"/>
```

which if i have text such as "this is a very long sentence"
comes out as
"this is a very long sen..."

but what i want to do is for it to cut off by words so it will output

"this is a very long..."
is there any way to do this?

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution yet?

Comment: No i never found a suitable answer.

Comment: Hi, have you found a solution yet?